# Download signed image from s3 does not work

Tags: amazon-s3, fetch

I have a strange issue relating to S3 signed URL

I want to download the file from S3 on my browser. Every file type worked as expected, **except the image** files. I do not know why

Here is my javascript

```
<html>
<script>
    fetch('<s3 signed url>', {
          method: 'GET',
          // For the image file, I always got the CORS error but for other file types, it works as expected
          // mode: 'no-cors',
        })
          .then((res) => {
            return res.blob();
          })
          .then((blob) => {
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'file.png';
            document.body.appendChild(a); 
            a.click();
          });
</script>
```

If I generated a signed URL for pdf or doc ... then download it with the above code, it works
But if I generated a signed URL for an image file and then download it with the above code, it does not work.
I always got this error in the console

```
Access to fetch at 'https://.......' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Then I added the

```
{mode: 'no-cors'}
```

Then it works but the context of the file is always empty (ZERO bytes)

Why? how can I download an image from S3?

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I am facing the same issue. if you find solution please post it here

Answer (score 0):

Did you try config CORS on S3 bucket policy?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html

Comment: Yes, my config is

[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "POST",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]